# how to use prepareStatement to update data, field and value both need be set

Tags: java, oracle, prepared-statement, sqlexception

I use `prepareStatement()` to update data, for several columns need to update, I wrote one procedure like this:

```
public boolean editSocre(String field, String newValue) 
{
... 

   updateSql = "update score set ? = ? where emp_id = ?";
   pstmt3 = conn.prepareStatement(updateSql);
   pstmt3.setString(1, field);
   pstmt3.setString(2, newValue);
   pstmt3.setString(3, userid);                 
   int row = pstmt3.executeUpdate();
   if (row <= 0) 
   {
      return result;
   }

...

}
```

> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column,
>   table.column, or column specification

How to modify, thanks!!

Comment: You cannot do this. `PreparedStatement` compiles the SQL statement so you must have to specify the column/field name.

Comment: You cannnot!!! This is the worst posibility i can imagine. OK, preparedStatement does not work, i can only use another.Thanks a lot! I don't need waste time on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public boolean editSocre(String field, String newValue) {

... 

updateSql = "update score set "+field+" = ? where emp_id = ?";

pstmt3 = conn.prepareStatement(updateSql);

pstmt3.setString(1, newValue);

pstmt3.setString(2, userid);          

int row = pstmt3.executeUpdate();

if (row <= 0) {

  return result;

}
```

...

Comment: This is not recommended. May be subject SQL injection.

Comment: @PaulVargas Correct me if I am wrong, but this would be subject to SQL Injection only if the field in question is provided, somehow, by the user. But it may be provided directly as a string literal in code, somewhere else or from a configuration file, in whose case it would not be subject to SQL injection.

Comment: Certainly. But it is a good practice to avoid the dynamic string concatenation in the query.

Comment: This is perfectly fine as long as `field` is only set internally. Hibernate pretty much does something similar.

Comment: I would however recommend passing in field as an enum instead that enumerates all the possible columns.

Answer (score 0):

As other answers/comments already say: this is not possible with PreparedStatement. You can use an updatable resultset if the row to update really needs to be dynamic:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM score WHERE emp_id = ?", ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
stmt.setString(1, userId);
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
if (rs.next()) { // or maybe while rs.next()
    rs.updateString(field, newValue);
    rs.updateRow();
}
```